# FileNotFoundError when creating a binary read only file in Python

Tags: python, file, ftp, binaryfiles

I'm creating an FTP client and am attempting to download from and upload files to an FTP server.

Downloading the files work fine as I have no issues creating a **write only binary file**, that does not initially exist on my local computer:

```
if cmnd1[0] == 'get':
    f1 = open('newDownloadText.txt', 'wb')
    ftp_cl.retrbinary("RETR " + cmnd1[1], f1.write, 1024)
    f1.close()
    ftp_cl.quit()
    break
```

However, I am unable to upload files to the server as I cannot successfully create a new **read only binary file**:

```
elif cmnd1[0] == 'put':
    f2 = open('newUploadTest.txt', 'rb')
    ftp_cl.storbinary("STOR " + cmnd1[1], f2)
    f2.close()
    ftp_cl.quit()
    break
```

My code fails when I attempt to create 'newUploadTest.txt'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 29, in <module>
    f2 = open('newUploadTest.txt', 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'newUploadTest.txt'
```

I have seen other posts on stackoverflow with individuals creating a new **read only binary files** without issues using 'rb' as a parameter, not sure why mine fails every time.

Comment: Probably the file named "newUploadTest.txt" does not exist in your current directory.

Comment: "rb" mode does not create files. That error is normal. You generally wouldn't _create_ a read only file to upload (it would always be empty). Did you expect the file to exist? Or do you really want to upload an empty file?

Comment: Can you reference one of the SO posts that create with 'rb'?

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

- File must be created before reading, whereas write mode creates the file.

> creating a new read only binary files

- `'rb'` mode does not ***Create read only binary***, but it reads a binary file which already exists.
- `'rb'` mode opens a binary file **which already exists** in a read only mode. It is not creating any file.

```
from os.path import isfile
if my_condition:
    file = 'newUploadTest.txt'
    # Check if the file exists
    if isfile(file):
        # open binary file
        f2 = open(file, 'rb')
        # do something...
        f2.close()
    else:
        print("File doesn't exists")
```